# Django - Filter objects by DateTimeField with a date range

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

I have a datetime field like below,

```
class Data(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I want to get the objects based on a date range from template form.
I have seen ways to filter for **DateField** but not for **DateTimeField**.
Can anyone help?

Comment: they should be the same. what have you tried so far? are you getting any error?

Comment: When you filter DateTime field, the value which is used to compare must has type of Python DateTime. You can use datetime.strptime to format DateTime variable from string, then apply operators like __gte __lte ... to filter.

Comment: @ruddra I tried instances = CameraData.objects.filter(time__range=["2020-05-19", "2020-05-20"]) . Using that, the error was ` RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField CameraData.time received a naive datetime (2020-05-20 00:00:00) while time zone support is active. `

Comment: @JayendraKantipudi I have reposted my comment to answer. Please make it the answer of your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you filter DateTime field, the value which is used to compare must has type of Python DateTime. You can use datetime.strptime to format DateTime variable from string, then apply operators like __gte __lte ... to filter.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this and since it helped me find a solution to my own problem I wanted to add some more specifics.

The error mentioned in comments being

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField [...] received a naive datetime [...] while time zone support is active.
```

basically just means that the date needs to be made aware for comparaison to work.
In this case, as per the comment to the question where the error is mentioned, the `range` operator should work just fine if that is fixed (and it does).
Instead of giving plain values to the operator, we merely need to give it an aware datetime value.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.utils import timezone

# the datetime value passed to make_aware() can be any datetime
# you could even use datetime.strptime() if you want
# (as mentioned in the accepted anwser)
# there are more ways to make datetime aware
# but this was simplest to me
aware_datetime = timezone.make_aware(datetime.now())

# storing the two dates for easier reading
start_date = aware_datetime - timedelta(days=1)
end_date = aware_datetime + timedelta(days=1)

filtered_qs = Model.objects.filter(DateTimeField__range=[start_date, end_date])
```