# Django QuerySet filter by Range with DateTimeField

Tags: python, django, postgresql, range, django-queryset

I tried to fix my queryset method, checked some answers on Stackoverflow, but still couldn't do it.

Basically i want to validate my form, so when there is an lesson within ceratin range, a Student cannot propose this specific timerange to it's lesson.

The problem is that when i try to find a queryset withing DateTimeField that exists, i still got an empty queryset:

My model:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Method in form:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    lesson_start_time = cleaned_data.get('start_time')
    lesson_end_time = cleaned_data.get('end_time')
    
    queryset = Lesson.objects.filter(start_time__range=(lesson_start_time,lesson_end_time))
    print(lesson_start_time) #2022-08-23 15:44:00+00:00
    print(lesson_end_time) #2022-08-23 15:36:00+00:00
    print(queryset) # <QuerySet []>
    
    if lesson_end_time < lesson_start_time:
        raise ValidationError("End time cannot be lower than start time!")
```

And there is for sure a Lesson Object within this range.

What i know for now is that it requeries something else to filter DateTimeField by range, but everything that i tried didn't work (for example: [Django - Filter objects by DateTimeField with a date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61949859/django-filter-objects-by-datetimefield-with-a-date-range)).

Could you please help me?

Comment: `lesson_end_time` is before `lesson_start_time` in your example, is the validation error stating this not being triggered?

Comment: That was being triggered, but i couldn't get an querryset. Fortunatelly we got and answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible: two ranges can overlap, without that the start time or end time is within the "range" of the other object. For example if the second object is *fully contained* by the first object.

You can fix this by first determining when two ranges do *not* overlap. Two ranges *[s<sub>1</sub>, e<sub>1</sub>]* and *[s<sub>2</sub>, e<sub>2</sub>]* do *not* overlap if *s<sub>1</sub><e<sub>2</sub>*, or *e<sub>1</sub><s<sub>2</sub>*. We can negate this expression to know when two intervals overlap: *s<sub>1</sub>≤e<sub>2</sub>*, and *e<sub>1</sub>≥s<sub>2</sub>*.

This thus means that we can check this with:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    start = cleaned_data['start_time']
    end = cleaned_data['end_time']

    queryset = Lesson.objects.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).filter(
        start_time__lte=end, end_time__gte=start
    )
    if end <= start:
        raise ValidationError('End time cannot be lower than start time!')
    if queryset.exists():
        raise ValidationError('There is an item with overlap!')
    return cleaned_data
```